# Reduce the width of the border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a simple animation using only css. The idea is that when I hover a social icon it will  seem like it's lifting up. I managed to do that but now i want to use "border" to seem like it's the icon's shadow. I reduced the thickness of the border on hover but I wanted to make it seem more realistic and somehow reduce the width of the border when hovering over. Any ideas? 
Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Iulius90/sck4Lzz9/

html

```
<div>
    <img src="http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/204/7/b/logo_skype_by_jackal807-d58ctxc.png">
</div>
```

css

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:tomato;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 50px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #222;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
}
div img:hover {
    margin-top: 22px;
    padding-bottom:28px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at using background gradients or box shadows instead.

Comment: Why use `border` instead of `box-shadow` for "realistic"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a solid linear gradient as a background image, and manipulate its dimensions upon hover. Note: You might want to use vendor prefixes to generate CSS gradients that are cross browser compatible.

```
img {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 3px;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 50px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
}
div img:hover {
    background-size: 50% 1px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    padding-bottom:28px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/sck4Lzz9/26/